# How to display current date and time on Django website?

Tags: python, html, django, datetime, bootstrap-4

I know how to print out current date and time in the console, but I am trying to add the date/time as a feature on my daily task Python website using Django and Bootstrap4.

I have tried adding it as a function in my views.py file and then inserting the function in the html file of the page i want it to be on, but everything I have tried has not worked.

Here is the function I created at first in views.py:

```
def today():
    """Shows todays current time and date."""
    today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p on %B %d, %Y")
    return today
```

Then I began playing around and tried this:

```
def today(request):
    """Shows todays current time and date."""
    today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p on %B %d, %Y")
    context = {'today': today}
    return render(request, context)
```

And this is what I tried adding to the html file:

```
<h4>{{ today }}</h4>
```

Update - Trying this and still does not show anything:

```
def today(request):
    """Shows todays current time and date."""
    today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p on %B %d, %Y")
    context = {'today': today}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)
```

Comment: and what you get? What is your problem ? Do you get empty page or error message ? We can't run you code and see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to display  only in the template then you can do [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#now)

```
Current datetime:{% now "jS F Y H:i" %}
```

Comment: As in 'your_template', do you mean the html file I want the date/time to show up? Because that did not work. I am trying to add date/time to the top of a page where there are user generated topics.

Comment: @arjun what if I wanna to get the value of current date value within my views.py with specific format ?

Answer (score 0):

```
return render(request, "example.html", context)
```

In your code templates name is missing, that's why function does not find any templates to render

Comment: Sorry that did not work, I updated the Q to show what I am trying now.

Comment: Check your settings file,  and find what is your staticfiles_dirs, I think your static path or any of path is in wrong, with regards

Answer (score -1):

Insert your template into a `<div>`:

{% now "jS F Y H:i" %}

```
<div class="small">
    Current datetime:{% now "jS F Y H:i" %}
</div>
```